# How i can restore the "doskey" function in Linux terminals?

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, lang

the short version its

1 - I Have a Multimedia Keyboyad .

Manufacturer : Genius
Model Name : KB29e or K641
Type : Multimedia + Calculator

2 - In some comment on facebook , someone told me , use in terminal something like

```
$ setxkbmap es
```

3 - Under Linux , this have 3 Keys for "Office" , but for years i dont find a method to get it work , in somewhere here in StackOverFlow , i found the answer , its a Software called "KeyTouch" & "KeyTouch Editor" . i has configured my Special Keys , and get working the Office Keys.

The Problem are :

1 - In the system , when i press in the keyboard , nothing happens when I press UP or DOWN Arrows (In all system , not working , in terminals , games , web browsers , etc)

2 - my Keyboard are "Spanish" but i can put accents over vocals.

Well someone knows i can fix thats problems ???

I see somewhere , in the terminal putting

```
$ set -o vi
```

and Pressing "ESC + K" show the command before use.
and Pressing "ESK + J" show the next command if you back various commands with "ESC +J"

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i has solved the "Arrow Keys : Up & Down" with

1 - Erasing : Scroll Up / Scroll Down , from the "KeyTouch" using the KeyTouch Editor

Erasing the file inside the `cd "/usr/share/keytouch/keyboards"`
Imported before by myself , with KeyTouch Software.

After Edit , Removing the "Scroll Up/Down" . and Importing Again

Configuring the Keyboard 
Using the follow command in CLI (under LinuxMint) :

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and rebooting . and ready the fix for Up and Down arrow keys
and with that i solved the accents too.